Cocompletion of groups
Hi I have the following task, show that the category of groups $\mathbf{Grp}$ is equivalent to $Ind(C)$ where $C$ is the category of finitely presented groups, and follow from that that the category of finitely presented groups is equivalent to a small category.
$Ind(C)$ are all functors $C^{op}\to \mathbf{Set}$ which commute with finite limits or equivalently are filtered colimits of such representable functors. My idea would be to define a functor $Ind(C) \to \mathbf{Grp}$ or the other way around and show it is a equivalence (e.g showing it is essentially surjective and fully faithfull) but I am not even able to define such a functor in any of the directions. Moreover I am not sure why it should follow that the category of finitely presented groups is equivalent to a small category as the category of groups is not small.

I suggest to not look at the example alone.
If $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ is a functor into a category with filtered colimits, then it extends to a functor $\overline{F} : \mathrm{Ind}(\mathcal{C}) \to \mathcal{D}$ which preserves filtered colimits. Namely, $\overline{F}(P) = \mathrm{colim}(\int P \xrightarrow{\pi} \mathcal{C} \xrightarrow{F} \mathcal{D})$. If we write $P \in \mathrm{Ind}(\mathcal{C})$ as a filtered colimit of representable functors, say $P = \mathrm{colim}_i \hom(-,x_i)$, then $\overline{F}(P) = \mathrm{colim}_i F(x_i)$. This is a basic result about the Ind-category, namely, its universal property.
Moreover, if $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ is fully faithful, and every object in the image is finitely presented, then $\overline{F} : \mathrm{Ind}(\mathcal{C}) \to \mathcal{D}$ is fully faithful as well. You can deduce this easily from the definitions of finitely presented objects and $\overline{F}$ above. If, moreover, every object of $\mathcal{D}$ is a filtered colimit of the objects in the image of $F$, then $\overline{F}$ is essentially surjective, and therefore an equivalence of categories.
The inclusion functor $\mathbf{Grp}_{fp} \hookrightarrow \mathbf{Grp}$ from finitely presented groups therefore extends to an equivalence $\mathrm{Ind}(\mathbf{Grp}_{fp}) \xrightarrow{\sim} \mathbf{Grp}$. This uses that the finitely presented groups (defined classically) are exactly the finitely presented objects in $\mathbf{Grp}$, and every group is a filtered colimit of finitely presented groups (this can be easily deduced from writing down a presentation and building it up from finite sub-presentations).
$\mathbf{Grp}_{fp}$ is essentially small: already the larger category $\mathbf{Grp}_{fg}$ of finitely generated groups is essentiall, since every such group is isomorphic to $F_n / U$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and a normal subgroup $U \subseteq F_n$, where $F_n$ denotes the free group on $n$ generators, and clearly the $F_n / U$ form a set. (A group is finitely presented if $U$ can be chosen to be finitely generated as a normal subgroup.) More generally, if $\kappa$ is any cardinal, then the category of groups that can be generated by $< \kappa$ elements is essentially small (here $\kappa=\aleph_0$).
